# Finding the largest element in a array based on another array and delete it (python 3.x)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am using python-3.x
I have two arrays, and I want to delete two rows that in (x) and (e) based on the largest two numbers in the (e) list:

```
 index
    0    x=[0 0 0 1 0]             e=[ [12]
    1      [1 1 1 1 0]                 [6 ] 
    2      [0 0 1 0 0] delete this row [20] --> the 1st largest number
    3      [1 1 1 1 1]                 [15] 
    4      [0 1 0 0 0]                 [0 ]
    5      [0 1 1 0 0] delete this row [18] --> the 2nd largest number
    6      [1 0 1 1 0]                 [11]
```

I tried many ways but for some reason, I can't solve it for example I tried this one:

```
l3 = list(zip(x, e))
#print(l3)
def maxx(n):
    max_val = 0
    index_val = 0
    l4 = l3[:n]

    for x,y in l4:
        if max_val < (y):
            max_val = (y)
            elem = (x, y)
            index_val = l3.index(elem)


    print ("max: ", max_val)
    print ("index of values:", index_val)
n = 20
maxx(n)
```

this code will return just one value with its index and if the largest number not in the index "0" then it will return error !!!!

also I have tried this code but it doesn't work properly !!!:

```
r = x[e.argpartition(2)[18:], :]
print (r)
```

please any suggestion or advice will be appreciated

Comment: Also in case I want to input the values randomly if I used {import numpy as np e= np.random.randint(5, size=(5)) x= np.random.randint (2, size=(5, 5))} is it will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `argpartition` in this way, firstly negate the `e` array, so that the largest values' index will be partitioned at the head of the result, after the partition, remove the first two indices and sort the remaining indices:

```
x[np.sort((-e.ravel()).argpartition(2)[2:]),:]

#matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

---

*used data*:

```
x = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

e = np.array([[12],[6],[20],[15],[0],[18],[11]])
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but why it giving an (IndexError: too many indices for array) if I usede {import numpy as np
e= np.random.randint(5, size=(5))
x= np.random.randint (2, size=(5, 5))} and how i can solve it

Comment: Also, can I delete the same row in the (e)? Becuse I want to delete them from both arrays (e) and (x)

Comment: The answer still works for the example you give. To delete the rows in `e`, you can do the same thing. `e[np.sort((-e.ravel()).argpartition(2)[2:])]` if e is one dimentional.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
def delete_row(x, e):
    # Find the max value and index
    index, value = max(enumerate(e), key=lambda x: x[1][0])

    # Delete the rows
    del x[index]
    del e[index]


x = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
]

e = [
    [12], [6], [20], [15],
    [0], [18], [11]
]

# Delete 2 rows
for _ in range(2):
    delete_row(x, e)
```

The result of the code above will be:

```
x = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
]

e = [
    [12], [6], [15],
    [0], [11]
]
```

I hope it help you :)

Comment: thank you so much, but in case I want to input the values randomly if I used {import numpy as np e= np.random.randint(5, size=(5)) x= np.random.randint (2, size=(5, 5))} is it will be the same. I should mention this in the question part, but I forget that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your question, too, without using `numpy` like this example:

```
x = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
e = [[12], [6], [20], [15], [0], [18], [11]]

def get_new_modified_list(a = list, b = list, max_index = 2):
    indexs = []
    a_copy = [k[0] for k in a]
    b_copy = b[:]
    for v in range(max_index):
        m = max(a_copy)
        # Find the max with it's occurrences
        indexs += [k for k in range(len(a_copy)) if a_copy[k] == m]

        i = 0
        for j in indexs:
            a_copy.pop(j-i)
            b_copy.pop(j-i)
            i+=1
        indexs = []

    return b_copy, a_copy

print(get_new_modified_list(e, x))
```

Output:

```
(
  [
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
 ],
 [
   [12], [6], [15], [0], [11]
 ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks. If my answer is helping you you can upvote it.